# Express is "resending" a request with undefined get param?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a express application, and I declared a route like this:

```
router.get('/single/:loId', learningObjectController.getLearningObject);
```

LearningObjects are just documents in the mongo database and de loId is the document I'm trying  to retrieve.

The page with the learning object fields is successfully loaded but then, another request with the :loId as undefined is made and a error is reported:

```
 /learning-object/single/undefined 500 237.271 ms - 5035
```

This is the learningObjectController.getLearningObject function:

```
    function getLearningObject(req, res) {
    let loId = req.params.loId;
    async.parallel({
        accessibility_resources: function(callback) {
            AccessibilityResources.find(callback);
        },
        axes: function(callback) {
            Axes.find(callback);
        },
        teaching_levels: function(callback) {
            TeachingLevels.find(callback);
        },
        resources: function(callback) {
            Resources.find(callback);
        },
        contents: function(callback) {
            Contents.find(callback);
        },
        licenses: function(callback) {
            Licenses.find(callback);
        },
        lo: function(callback) {
            LearningObject.findById(loId, callback);
        }
    }, function(err, results) {        
        res.render('lo_update', { error: err, data: results });
    });
}
```

As you can see, this is  a very simple method to retrieve the finded learningObject by it's _id(loId).

Why is that second get request made?

Sorry about my english and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you certain it's express? It's more likely that it's your client code. If you are that unsure you would be better off with a better logger. Not making recommendations but something like [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) can produce a "combined" log format, which is common to larger web servers. Part of the request logged is the User Agent, as well as the IP address. To me this looks like you are "presuming" it's server code, when it likely is not. So you should be sure of the source first.

Comment: Yeah man, it was all about the client, when I look at the network tab on the browser I see that the request came from the JS... Dropzone was trying to get the learningObject imagem from a incorrect url, by coincidence that incorrect url match the route I showed before. Now, both image loading and route are working properly.